# Как разбить отрезок на пропорционально уменьшающиеся части?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Нужно разбить отрезок на неравные части, которые будут пропорционально уменьшаться (нужно графически отобразить временную шкалу).

Дано:

1. длина отрезка - может быть любым числом в промежутке от 100 до 1000;
2. кол-во частей - 24;
3. длина первой части ~ 15% +- - значение не фиксировано.

В ответе я опубликовал сове решение, но надеюсь получить более верный, математически правильный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если отрезки образуют геометрическую прогрессию, то для её суммы можно записать

```
 L = (0.15 * L) * (q^n-1)/ (q-1)
 (1 - q^24) / (1 - q) = 6.66666
```

Для нахождения знаменателя ГП q можно решить это уравнение численно с использованием бинарного поиска или другого метода

Для поиска - задаём интервал поиска (если знаем, что отрезки будут уменьшаться - то 0..1) и постепенно приближаемся к более-менее точному решению (функция монотонна, поэтому любой метод будет сходиться).

Вот очень простой [метод секущих](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4)  (код не проверял)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
double f(double x) {
    return (1.0d - exp(24.0d*logf(x)))/(1.0d-x) - 6.6666667d; 
}

// a, b - пределы хорды, epsilon — необходимая погрешность
double findRoot(double a, double b, double epsilon) {
    while(fabs(b - a) > epsilon) {
        a = b - (b - a) * f(b) / (f(b) - f(a));
        b = a + (a - b) * f(a) / (f(a) - f(b));
    }
    // a, b — (i - 1)-й и i-й члены

    return b;
}

q = findRoot(0.0d, 1.0d, 0.000001d)
```

Comment: К сожалению, у меня не хватает знаний, чтобы оценить Ваш ответ.) Не мог ли бы Вы расписать ответ более подробно?

Comment: А что именно смущает  - геометрическая прогрессия или численный поиск решения?

Comment: численный поиск

Answer (score 1):

```js
const width = 300;
const segments = 24;
const startWidth = (width / 100) * 15;
const step = 0.9;
let result = [startWidth];
let count = 0 //счетчик итераций
let sum = 99999; // аккумулятор общей длины всех отрезков

//формируется массив с базовыми отрезками
for (let i = 0; i < segments - 1; i++) {
  const item = result[result.length - 1];
  result.push(item * step);
}

//вычисялется разница между длиной получившегося массива и нужным результатом
//с этой разницы формируется массив отрезков по такому же принципу как и базовый
//потом эти недоотрезки вычитаются из базовых отрезков
//и так по кругу, пока сумма всех отрезков не будет равна необходимой длине

while ( count < 500 && Math.floor(sum) > width ) {
  //если округлять в большую сторону, то кол-во итерация многократно увеличивается
  count++;
  console.log(`Итерация №: ${count}`)
  const d = result.reduce((sum, index) => sum + index) - width;
  const between = [d / segments];

  for (let i = 0; i < segments - 1; i++) {
    const item = between[between.length - 1];
    between.push(item * step);
  }
  result = result.map((item, index) => {
    return item - between[index];
  });
  sum = result.reduce((sum, index) => sum + index);
}

console.log(result);
console.log(`Сумма всех отрезков: ${result.reduce((sum, index) => sum + index)}`);
```